# Ruby-on-Rails Create Record from Rake Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, rake, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following rake task and user controller im attempting to load users into the database from a csv using the `create` action as follows:

lib/tasks/import_users_csv.rake:

```
desc "Import Users from csv file"
task :import_users => [:environment] do

  file = "db/users.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
    User.create(
      :name => row[1],
      :email => row[2],
      :password => row[3],
      :password_confirmation => row[4],
      :admin => row[5],
      :role => row[6]
    )
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "User " + @user.name.to_s + " sucessfully created"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role, :admin)
end
```

unfortunately when I try to run the task (`rake import_users_csv:import_users`) I get the error dont know how to build task 'import_users_csv:import_users'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the task in the proper namespace? The way you are running the task, it needs to be inside the `:import_users_csv` namespace:

```
namespace :import_users_csv do

  desc "Import Users from csv file"
  task :import_users => [:environment] do

   file = "db/users.csv"

    CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
      User.create({
        :name => row[1],
        :email => row[2],
        :password => row[3],
        :password_confirmation => row[4],
        :admin => row[5],
        :role => row[6]
      })
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't want the namespace, you should just be able to `rake import_users`. Use `rake -T` to see a list of rake tasks that you can run. You should see yours listed there.

**Edit:**

The `CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|` call will actually give you back a `Hash` where the keys are the values in the header row. If you have the following CSV file:

```
Foo,Bar,Baz
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

You'll want to access it like this:

```
:foo => row['Foo'],
:bar => row['Bar'],
:baz => row['Baz']
```

Comment: Thanks! this resolves the error, unfortunately the task doesn't appear to do anything alas.

Comment: @user2732663 Ah, you are using `:headers => true`. That makes `row` a hash, so you'll need to use the header values to access the contents of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your task `task :import_users => [:environment]` requires another parameter (the environment), try to run it as `rake import_users_csv:import_users:development` for instance.

EDIT:

You actually don't have the namespace, your task is called with `rake import_users:development`

Comment: doesn't make a difference I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry I missed the namespace thing, you actually don't have a namespace, just a description, so you can't use the `import_users_csv` in the rake task call.